# TFS: "Source control folder" as parameter in build definition

Tags: tfs, build-definition

As i understand the "Source control folder" (under "Source settings" tab of build definition) is used to specify the path from where the source code will be downloaded.  Is there any way this can be made as build parameter?  If so, please share the solution.

Reason: In our project there are several branches and each of them has its own build template and build definition settings, the above solution will help us in creating just one build definition for all the branches.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
spm

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add download files activity in templates and pass the source control path as a parameter.